# SQL Dynamic Join

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

Need Suggestion for making below query Dynamic for different timestamps

trying to add below conditions (Same Day, 1 Day, 7 Days, 15 Days, 30 Days), dau_funnel contains millions of records

```
dc.at_date_ist between m.install_ist::date and m.install_ist::date + 0
dc.at_date_ist between m.install_ist::date and m.install_ist::date + 1
dc.at_date_ist between m.install_ist::date and m.install_ist::date + 7
dc.at_date_ist between m.install_ist::date and m.install_ist::date + 15
dc.at_date_ist between m.install_ist::date and m.install_ist::date + 30
```

Query Joining Clause:

```
select count(distinct user_id) from mapping m
    left join dau_funnel dc on m.user_id = dc.custom__user_id and m.device_uuid = dc.device_uuid 
        and dc.at_date_ist between m.install_ist::date and m.install_ist::date + 7
```

Answer (score 0):

Use conditional aggregation, and take separate count expressions:

```
select
    count(distinct user_id) as cnt_0,
    count(distinct case when c.at_date_ist  between m.install_ist::date and m.install_ist::date + 1  then user_id end) as cnt_1,
    count(distinct case when dc.at_date_ist between m.install_ist::date and m.install_ist::date + 7  then user_id end) as cnt_7,
    count(distinct case when dc.at_date_ist between m.install_ist::date and m.install_ist::date + 15 then user_id end) as cnt_15,
    count(distinct case when dc.at_date_ist between m.install_ist::date and m.install_ist::date + 30 then user_id end) as cnt_30
from mapping m
left join dau_funnel dc
    on m.user_id = dc.custom__user_id and m.device_uuid = dc.device_uuid;
```

Comment: This Syntax is not supported by Redshift..Any other Solution

Comment: @SQL_Learner I must have missed the Redshift tag.  Please don't tag with Postgres unless you are really using that database.

Comment: @SQL_Learner . . . What part of this syntax is not supported by RedShift?  `COUNT DISTINCT` is supported as an aggregation function (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COUNT.html) as is `CASE`.  This SQL is quite standard.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Originally, I had used `FILTER` in my answer.  Redshift is a fork of a really old version of Postgres, which apparently did not yet support `FILTER`.